# Flutter:Checkbox onChange does not update UI even tough the value changes

Tags: flutter

I'm building a To App in flutter and I want to change the boolean value of my individual todo by using a checkbox. While the value does change it is not reflected in the UI. Did I do something wrong?

In the beginning, I did not use a boolean to change the value of my Todo's completed property. I tried to change it with the checkbox but It did not seem to work and that's why I put a boolean instead.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import './todo.dart';

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'To do app',
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List _myTodos = [
    Todo(title: 'Take the dogs for a walk', completed: false, id: '1'),
    Todo(title: 'Go out for a run', completed: true, id: '2')
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('To do app'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: _myTodos.isEmpty
          ? Text(
              'Press the button to add a new Todo',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            )
          : Column(
              children: _myTodos.map((todo) {
              bool completed = todo.completed;
              return Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Checkbox(
                    value: completed,
                    onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                      print(completed);
                      setState(() {
                        completed = newValue;
                        print(completed);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  Text(
                    todo.title,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                  )
                ],
              );
            }).toList()),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        elevation: 8,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you assigning it to a new bool ? `bool completed = todo.completed;`

Try without assigning it, just use `value: todo.completed,` and  `todo.completed =newValue;`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That's what I did in the beginning but I've gotten this error message 

`Class 'Todo' has no instance setter 'completed='.
Receiver: Instance of 'Todo'
Tried calling: completed=true`

Comment: and also use `CheckboxListTile` like: `children: _myTodos.map((todo) => CheckboxListTile(
controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
title: Text(
  todo.title,
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
),
value: todo.completed,
onChanged: (bool newValue) => setState(() => todo.completed = newValue),
)
).toList()`

Comment: Thank you, I've refactored my code :)

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers. I found out what was my issue. In my Todo class, I have set my completed value as final so of course, I wasn't able to change it when I pressed it.